# Is iText or iTextSharp capable of setting the edit password on a PDF

Tags: itext

Is iText or iTextSharp capable of setting the edit password on a PDF?

I know when we use itextsharp to create a PDF, it can set a password to open the PDF. But I have not found a way to set up a password for editing PDF.

Comment: What is *"editPDF"*?

Comment: there are access permissions to allow/disallow modifying the document's contents. Is this what you mean?